# Elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera "Failed to set MoKListRT:

Tags: release-hera

After installing the OS, removing the USB, and pressing Enter to reboot, it shows a black screen with the text:

```
"Failed to set MoKListRT: Invalid Parameter
Could not create MoKListRT: -Invalid Parameter
Importing MOK states has failed: import_mok_state()C: Invalid Parameter
Continuing boot since secure mode is disable"
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This may be able to help you: [Linux Mint Forums: Failed to set MokListRT: Invalid Parameter](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=337744)